Interchange of partial derivatives in matrix calculus
According to Magnus and Neudecker, we can build a matrix calculus without running into higher order tensors by vectorizing the matrices before taking partial derivatives. This leads to the matrix Jacobian defined as
$$
\mathrm{DZ}(X)=\frac{\partial \operatorname{vec} Z(X)}{\partial(\operatorname{vec} X)^{\mathsf{T}}} \,.
$$
Now let's say we have some function that takes in 2 matrices and gives out another matrix $F:\mathbb{R}^{k \times l} \times \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \to \mathbb{R}^{p \times q}$. Let's call our input matrices $A^{k \times l}$ and $B^{m \times n}$, and the output matrix $Y^{p \times q}$. So $Y = F(A,B)$.
My question: how can I interchange the order of partial derivatives? For example,
given
$ \frac{\partial \frac{\partial Y}{\partial A}}{\partial B} ,$
how do I get
$ \frac{\partial \frac{\partial Y}{\partial B}}{\partial A} ?$
(where I ommited $\operatorname{vec}$ and transpose for brevity)
By trial and error with a symbolic toolbox I have arrived at this useless expression, since I cannot solve one in terms of the other:
$$ \operatorname{vec} \frac{\partial \operatorname{vec} \left( \frac{\partial \operatorname{vec} Y}{\partial (\operatorname{vec} A)^\mathsf{T}}\right)^\mathsf{T}}{\partial(\operatorname{vec}B)^\mathsf{T} } = \operatorname{vec} \left( \frac{\partial\operatorname{vec}\frac{\partial \operatorname{vec} Y}{\partial (\operatorname{vec} B)^\mathsf{T}} }{\partial (\operatorname{vec} A)^\mathsf{T}}\right)^\mathsf{T}   $$
I tried using the commutation matrix to eliminate the transpose on the RHS but with no success. Any ideas?
Reference: J. Magnus and H. Neudecker, Matrix Differential Calculus with Applications in Statistics and Econometrics, 3rd edition, 2019, Wiley.

Thank you greg for your answer. Your example motivated me to dig deeper and find the relation I needed for switching the order of partial derivatives.
Is there any nice, explicit, function such that
$ g\left(\frac{\partial \frac{\partial Y}{\partial B}}{\partial A}\right) =  \frac{\partial \frac{\partial Y}{\partial A}}{\partial B}  $? Yes! Moreover, it can be written in terms of $\operatorname{vec}$, Kroneker product $\otimes$, and good old matrix multiplication together with some identity and commutation matrices.
In the following derivation I am going to skip writing $\operatorname{vec}$ and transpose before $\partial$, remembering to always vectorize the matrices before taking partials, and then arranging the partials like a Jacobian.
Starting from the experimental result above, it turns out we can manipulate it until we get rid of all transposes. On the right hand side,
$$ RHS = K^{(pqmn,kl)} \operatorname{vec} \frac{\partial\frac{\partial Y}{\partial B}}{\partial A}  \,.$$
On the left hand side there is more work to do:
\begin{align}
LHS &= \operatorname{vec}\frac{\partial K^{(pq,kl)}\operatorname{vec}\frac{\partial Y}{\partial A}}{\partial B} \\
&= \operatorname{vec} \left[ \left(I_1 \otimes K^{(pq,kl)} \right) \frac{\partial \operatorname{vec} \left(\operatorname{vec}\frac{\partial Y}{\partial A}\right)}{\partial B} \right] \\
&= \operatorname{vec} \left(K^{(pq,kl)} \frac{\partial \frac{\partial Y}{\partial A}}{\partial B} \right) \\
&= \left( I_{mn} \otimes K^{(pq,kl)} \right) \operatorname{vec}\frac{\partial \frac{\partial Y}{\partial A}}{\partial B} \,.
\end{align}
So now we can say $LHS = RHS$ which is a closed-form relationship between the vectorized versions of our mixed partial derivatives,
$$ \left( I_{mn} \otimes K^{(pq,kl)} \right) \operatorname{vec}\frac{\partial \frac{\partial Y}{\partial A}}{\partial B} = K^{(pqmn,kl)} \operatorname{vec} \frac{\partial\frac{\partial Y}{\partial B}}{\partial A} \,.$$
To obtain one in terms of the other, we need the inverse of vectorization,
a sort of arcvec, that returns a matrix from a column vector. The subscript in $\operatorname{vec}_{m\times n}^{-1}$ indicates the size of the resulting matrix. So
$$\frac{\partial \frac{\partial Y}{\partial A}}{\partial B} = \operatorname{vec}_{pqkl\times mn}^{-1} \left[ \left( I_{mn} \otimes K^{(pq,kl)} \right)^{-1} K^{(pqmn,kl)} \operatorname{vec} \frac{\partial\frac{\partial Y}{\partial B}}{\partial A}  \right]$$
which expanded out reads
$$\frac{\partial \frac{\partial Y}{\partial A}}{\partial B} = \left[ (\operatorname{vec}I_{mn})^{\mathsf{T}} \otimes I_{pqkl} \right] \left( I_{mn} \otimes \left[ \left( I_{mn} \otimes K^{(pq,kl)} \right)^{-1} K^{(pqmn,kl)} \operatorname{vec} \frac{\partial \frac{\partial Y}{\partial B}}{\partial A}\right] \right) \,.$$
The other way around is analogous. I tested the formula in my symbolic toolbox and it seems correct. What is interesting to me is how this vectorization-based matrix calculus preserves short, nice, expressions for the product rule and chain rule, but a simple task like changing the order of partial derivatives is a headache!

$
\def\c{\cdot}
\def\q{\quad}
\def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\phix{y_k}
\def\p{{\partial}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\hess#1#2#3{\frac{\p^2 #1}{\p #2\,\p #3^T}}
$You have re-discovered the following result
$$\eqalign{
\hess{\phi}{a}{b}
 &= \left(\hess{\phi}{b}{a}\right)^T 
 \ne \hess{\phi}{b}{a} \\
}$$
where
$$\eqalign{
a &= \vc A,\q b=\vc B,\q  y=\vc Y,\qq \phi=\phix \\
}$$
Since $\phi$ is a scalar and $\{a,b\}$ are vectors of different lengths, then from dimensional considerations alone one can see that
The LHS gradient is a rectangular matrix with the shape of the outer product $\,ab^T$
The RHS gradient is also rectangular, but it is shaped like the outer product $\:ba^T$


Here is a simple concrete example
$$\eqalign{
&\;\;\phi \;= \LR{Mb}\c a \;\,\,=\; \LR{M^Ta}\c b  \\
g_a = &\grad{\phi}{a} = Mb \q
  \qiq \hess{\phi}{b}{a} = \grad{g_a}{b} = M \\
g_b = &\grad{\phi}{b} = M^Ta\;
  \qiq\hess{\phi}{a}{b} = \grad{g_b}{a} = M^T \\
}$$
